# Server / Client Connection Outside Local Computer

Tags: sockets, connection, server

Hi I have a socket Server / Client program written in Java I wan't to use this on to devices like Android Phone Client and Mac/Pc Server. My code runs perfect but I'm a bit confuse on How I'm making this connection between devices?. I was thinking on renting a server that supports Java but I'm still not sure yet.

Can someone gave me some tips on this? The server use sockets by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the socket connection is doing for example if the application is for chat then you probably need a server and every client is handled by a thread in the server

Comment: Yeah one part of it is a chat room. So I do need a Server to keep it Online and connect it over the internet?. This is a simple app for education

Comment: then go for a cheap VPS plan and configure a java socket server  as you wish this will give you control over your server (Please vote my answer if you liked it thanks)